# List of invertible congruence classes

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am attempting to create a list of the invertible congruence classes $\bmod 120$.

The code I have is `Table[If[{ModularInverse[i, 120]} = {}, 120, ModularInverse[i, 120]], {i, 
  0, 119}]`

If the modular inverse does not exist, it should return $120$. If it does exist, it should return the integer that corresponds to the inverse congruence class.

The code is not working how I expected it to. If the modular inverse does not exists, it gives me a list with the unevaluated code, for example, `ModularInverse[0, 120]`.

Comment: Not the only problem, but one thing to note: Equality is tested with a double-equals `==`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note what happens when `i` does not have an inverse:

```
ModularInverse[2, 120]
```

> ModularInverse::ninv: 2 is not invertible modulo 120.

```
(*  Out[]=  ModularInverse[2, 120]  *)
```

The output is the same as the input (it returns "unevaluated" in *Mma* jargon).
You can use `FreeQ` to see if the inverse returned unevaluated:

```
Table[With[{inv = Quiet@ModularInverse[i, 120]}, 
  If[FreeQ[inv, ModularInverse], inv, 120]], {i, 0, 119}]
```

Comment: You can also use `Check[]`: `Table[Quiet[Check[ModularInverse[i, 120], 120, ModularInverse::ninv]], {i, 0, 119}]`.